# Minimize code in c#

Tags: c#

```
var newObject = keyValuePair.Key;
var originalObject = keyValuePair.Value;
List<ChargeBITValue> bitValues = new List<ChargeBITValue>();
foreach (var item in originalObject.ChargeBITValues)
{
    ChargeBITValue bitValue = new ChargeBITValue()
    {
        ChargeTypeEnumID = item.ChargeTypeEnumID,
        DataValue = item.DataValue,
        ClientTripTypeContractChargeValueList = newObject
    };
    bitValues.Add(bitValue);
}
```

I have similar loops for rest of the values, bitValues, moneyValues, Rupees Values, how can I remove the duplication from my code?

Comment: Please include the type of the `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`

Comment: Not only that but for _all_ the types involved.

Answer (score 6):

First, if you don't have it already, you need to define a common **Interface** that is implemented by `ChargeBITValue`, `ChargeMoneyValue`, `ChargeRupeeValue` etc (you need to adapt the interface using the actual types of your properties instead of `int`, `List<string>` and `IEnumerable<IChargeValue>`). Let' call it `IChargeValue`:

```
interface IChargeValue
{
    int ChargeTypeEnumID { get; set; }
    int DataValue { get; set; }
    List<string> ClientTripTypeContractChargeValueList { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IChargeValue> ChargeValues { get; }
}
```

Then, you change your method to use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and type constraints:

```
private void YourMethod<T>() where T : IChargeValue, new()
{
    // KeyValuePair<YourTKey, YourTValue> keyValuePair = new ...
    var newObject = keyValuePair.Key;
    var originalObject = keyValuePair.Value;
    List<T> values = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in originalObject.ChargeValues)
    {
        T value = new T()
        {
            ChargeTypeEnumID = item.ChargeTypeEnumID,
            DataValue = item.DataValue,
            ClientTripTypeContractChargeValueList = newObject
        };
        values.Add(value);
    }
}
```

If you want to, you can use LINQ instead of the foreach statement:

```
var values =
    from item in originalObject.ChargeValues
    select new T
    {
        ChargeTypeEnumID = item.ChargeTypeEnumID,
        DataValue = item.DataValue,
        ClientTripTypeContractChargeValueList = newObject
    };
List<T> valuesAsList = values.ToList();
```

Comment: Though the LINQ code would need a final `ToList()` call to make it complete.

Comment: @Jeff that depends on whether he really needs to have the values in a List. Possibly an IEnumerable<T> will do, but thanks for pointing out the discrepancy between my answer and his example code.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your correction - it serves to remind us of deferred execution as well.

Comment: @Manvinder has this answer helped you? Is it unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer - but building on codesparkle's code, how about something like this lambda expression instead of LINQ/`foreach` statements (looks less verbose):

```
var bitValues = originalObject.ChargeBITValues.Select(item => new T
    {
        ChargeTypeEnumID = item.ChargeTypeEnumID,
        DataValue = item.DataValue,
        ClientTripTypeContractChargeValueList = newObject
    });
```

Comment: you'll need to decide between using `a` or `item` as a parameter for the lambda.